# Spring Data, JPA, and Hibernate: why does my object gets saved with the save statement removed?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am doing a Spring web application using Spring Data, JPA, and Hibernate. I am testing things and notice that my object gets saved even after I removed the save statement in the service layer. Here are the details:

----- data ----

```
public interface FriendGroupRepository extends CrudRepository<FriendGroup, Long>, FriendGroupRepositoryCustom {
}
```

The methods defined in FriendGroupRepositoryCustom are not used in my test. The test involves only one method from the CrudRepository interface.

----- service ----

```
@Service
@Repository
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService  {

@Override
@Transactional
public void saveFriendGroup(FriendGroup group) {
    friendGroupRepository.save(group);
}

}
```

**After I removed friendGroupRepository.save(group); from the above, the object still gets saved into database. I did debug and trace and confirmed that this method was indeed invoked when I submit a form.**

------ web controller ---------

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/formtest"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String formPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
    Model model, Map<String, Object> map,
        @ModelAttribute("command") FriendGroup fg,
        BindingResult result, 
        SessionStatus status ){

    ......
    accountService.saveFriendGroup(fg);     
    .......
}
```

I am quite confused and not sure what is wrong. If more code or config is needed, please let me know.

Thanks for any help!
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature, see the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html#objectstate-modifying):

> Transactional persistent instances (i.e. objects loaded, saved,
>   created or queried by the Session) can be manipulated by the
>   application, and any changes to persistent state will be persisted
>   when the Session is flushed. This is discussed later in this chapter.
>   There is no need to call a particular method (like update(), which has
>   a different purpose) to make your modifications persistent.

The Hibernate session keeps a cache of all entities loaded in it and keeps track of changes to them, when the session is flushed it issues SQL updates to persist those changes to the database. Therefore, if your object is in a persistent state (you've loaded it in the current session), any changes to it will get persisted without calling save.

Comment: Nathan, thanks sooooo much for your input. So the invoke of friendGroupRepository.save(group) is not needed to save the object, correct?

Comment: @curious1: right, as long as the object is loaded in the same Hibernate session.